# Eager loading a tree with nHibernate re-queries leaf nodes

Tags: nhibernate, orm, tree, nhibernate-mapping, eager-loading

Looking for some expertise before I declare the NHibernate framework broken or myself crazy!

I'm trying to eagerly load a self-referencing tree with NHibernate and can successfully load most children lists, however I can't seem to get it to work with leaf nodes.  My query is:

```
"select p from Proposal p join fetch p.Structures s join fetch s.theChildrenList c " +
"where p._persistenceId = :p1 and s.theProposal = :p1 and c.theProposal = :p1")
.SetParameter("p1", aProposalId)
.SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer()).
UniqueResult<Proposal>();
```

This will return all the records correctly, but does not properly populate the childrenList of leaf nodes (which should be by definition empty).  Instead when I get a proxy and upon searching the tree, thousands of pointless zero record queries.

I've tried:
1. using left join rather than join 
2. Making the children's list not-lazy and fetch="join" and removing the hql (as a proof of concept, performance downside is unacceptable elsewhere)
3. Messing with the not-found property that I saw someone use in the hibernate forums

All of which give me the same results... one large query with all the data (good) and thousands of small queries which return no data (bad).  Any ideas?

I'm using NHibernate 2.2 and here is the relevant part of the mappings file for reference:

```
  <many-to-one    name="theParentStructure"
                  column="PARENT_STRUCTURE_ID"
                  class="Structure"
                  access="field"
                  update="false"
                  insert="false"
                  not-found="ignore"/>

  <bag            name="theChildrenList"
                  generic="true"
                  table="STRUCTURE"
                  access="field"
                  cascade="all-delete-orphan"
                  inverse="true" fetch="join" lazy="false">  <--Both with and without the last two properties
     <key column="PARENT_STRUCTURE_ID" />
     <one-to-many class="Structure"/>
  </bag>
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

I was interested in this topic quite some time ago, so please don't take everything that I say for granted (maybe someone with more `NHibernate` experience could correct me in case I'm wrong).

Last time I've checked the described situation was quite a problem as `Nhibernate` was generating separate queries for each `level` of child entities. If you know in advance that your depth of the tree is not going to be extremely big than probably you could live without the `eager loading` of children... But if your structure is not limited in depth you should probably look into alternatives.

**Assuming you are using SqlServer**

One solution that I've found quite easy to implement was to use the `recursive self-join` / `CTE`. This solution involves switching to `stored-procedures` as the source of your query and to re-create the hierarchy manually in code. To fetch entire tree you only need one db query (which can include all sorts of filters and sub-queries + ordering) and you can still re-use your `NHibernate` mappings for all `CRUD` operations. One disadvantage of this solution is that you later on have to maintain the query code on the db side (column and mapping changes etc.).

**Modified preorder tree traversal algorithm**

This is my `ideal` solution for tree persistence as it does not require any `stored-procedures` and can be perfectly integrated with `NHibernate` and the `Criteria API` (which for me is a huge advantage as I can freely create advanced and reusable filters in code). From the performance point of view all selects are almost cost free - you move the balance towards the insert, update and delete operations as you need to re-calculate the tree on every change - but this can be done with `hql` like so (pseudo-code):

```
HQLNamedQuery hql = new HQLNamedQuery();
hql.Query = "UPDATE " + typeof(THierarchy).FullName +
    " SET TraversalLeft = (TraversalLeft + :traversalChange) " +
    " WHERE BaseNodeId = :baseNodeId AND TraversalLeft > :minTr AND TraversalLeft <= :maxTr";
```

I've managed to implement all sorts of operations using this technique (like add, add range, move, re-order, get descendants, get ancestors, count descendants etc.) and I have to say that once you get the basic principle you can perfectly integrate it in different projects.

Link to the article that got me started on this topic (it doesn't use `NHibernate` unfortunately):
http://weblogs.asp.net/aghausman/archive/2009/03/16/storing-retrieving-hierarchical-data-in-sql-server-database.aspx

**Mapping a tree in NHibernate**

Maybe you should also take a look at this post (exact part starts from `An alternative approach`):
http://nhibernate.hibernatingrhinos.com/16/how-to-map-a-tree-in-nhibernate

This basically comes down to adding two additional collections to your mapping: `Ancestors` and `Descendants` and performing three queries: main query, load ancestors and load descendants - this should prevent NHibernate from performing additional queries when accessing child nodes.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting thought on the preorder tree traversal, but traversing the tree isn't my problem, its _getting_ the tree! I've actually looked into your first solution (well, the oracle version 'link by prior'), but it doesn't seem to solve the underlying problem of nHibernate re-querying all the leaf nodes. My current code gets all the correct data, nHibernate just doesn't seem to understand that the lack of rows when you have no children is because they 'don't exist' not that we haven't queried for them yet...

Comment: I have updated my answer - I have added a link to a nice article about mapping trees in NHibernate but to be honest I don't think that you can easily prevent additional queries without 'hacks/tricks'. On the other hand why can you just re-create the hierarchy structure yourself and update the mapping so that child entities are not queried through proxy?

Comment: I was hoping to not have to recreate the basis of the structure as it is the foundation of the entire system, but the more I look at this problem, the more it seems like this might have to be the answer (here comes at least another month of re-coding a legacy app...)  I was hoping for something more along the lines of what Ayende talks about here: [link](http://ayende.com/blog/4151/nhibernate-tips-tricks-efficiently-selecting-a-tree)

Answer (score 0):

I think the root cause is that NHibernate has no way to know that the query returns all records in the hierarchy. That is, it doesn't know that a node is a leaf node. How could it?

My quick-and-dirty solution would be to add a method to Proposal that selects the lead nodes and replaces the proxy collection with a new empty collection. Basically you would inform Proposal that it is fully populated by calling this method.

Comment: By doing this wouldn't this confuse nHibernate into thinking all the leaf nodes were dirty and make it issue an equivalent number of update statements?

Comment: I don't think so. Even if they do get flagged as dirty, they wouldn't have any members so no database calls would be issued. Check NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized to determine if the collection is a proxy or not and assign it to an empty collection if it's a proxy.